# iOS firebase authentication with Facebook

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Hi i tried to make Firebase Facebook Authentication.

But there are some problems. I can get Facebook Email by Firebase,
but if i change the view after login success, I cannot get Facebook Email by

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
```

I can check my Facebook email on Firebase Authentication Console.

Google, and normal email authentication works, but facebook is not.

this is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{

// facebook Login
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error!) {
    if result?.token == nil {return}


    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)


    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
}


// facebook logout
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

}


@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var facebookLogin: FBSDKLoginButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    facebookLogin.delegate = self
    facebookLogin.readPermissions = ["email"]

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: nil)
        }

    }
}


@IBAction func googleSignBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}


@IBAction func emailLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email.text!, password: self.password.text!) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.email.text!, password: self.password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            })

        }else{

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Sign up Success!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Firebase Auth does not return these kind of details. It is a good practice to store all the details in Firebase Database as shown in the below image under the `Database.database().reference().child("uid")`

[User profile Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8zYE.png)